# applicationSettings ignored in web.config

Tags: feature, configuration, web-config, xml

I've written a feature assembly that includes an `SPFeatureReceiver`. I can successfully deploy the feature's WSP, the assembly goes to the GAC, and the feature (mostly) does what it's supposed to. However, when I edit the settings here for both the application and web frontend servers in the farm:

`c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\443\web.config`

And add this to `configuration/configSections`:

```
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="MyAssembly.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

And add this to `configuration`:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <MyAssembly.Properties.Settings>
    <setting> ...
    </setting>
  </MyAssembly.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Those settings are ignored, and the `System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute` values are being used instead. So. Where is this assembly looking for its settings?

---

## Edit

As it turns out, it was trying to load from here:
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.config`, and sometimes `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\30482\web.config` (neither of which are the correct SharePoint folders).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Property bags and SharePoint content database usage might be the best way to go, if it weren't for the fact that I need to also store settings that tell the application how to connect to SharePoint in the first place.

I ended up writing a simple module that saves everything to one explicitly specified .config, using the System.Configuration namespace, and writing custom ConfigurationSection classes. Now I can be guaranteed to know where the settings are being stored; I don't need any SharePoint dependencies to do settings (just .NET itself); and I don't need to add any third-party software (such as PBM) to be able to edit the settings outside of the application.

Comment: Use the SPFeatureReceiverProperties to connect to SharePoint.

Comment: I agree with Tom or use property bags approach.

Comment: This is *not* a recommended approach for storing settings in SharePoint. Use Hierarchical Configuration Manager as Tom mentions in his answer

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find that changing web.config files to store application settings for SharePoint Features is not your best solution.

For an alternate solution that may work better for you, please refer to the [Applications Setting Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx) of the Microsoft Patterns and Practice SharePoint Guidance.

SharePoint 2007 guidance includes a section on [Managing Application Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413935.aspx) that discuses web.config changes through APIs. However, in practice, those have proven less reliable than the updated guidance which stores properties in the configuration database.

Comment: +1 This is how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with `SPWebConfigModification` class to perform web configuration (web.config) changes across SharePoint farm.

```
class WebConfigReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{
        private const string MyOwner = "OwnerName";

        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            string name, xpath, value;

            SPWebApplication webApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;

            #region ..: appSettings :..
            name = "add[@key='TestKey']";
            xpath = "configuration/appSettings";
            value = "<add key='TestKey' value='MyValue' />";
            ModifyWebConfig(webApp, name, xpath, value, SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode);

            name = "add[@key='KeyName']";
            xpath = "configuration/appSettings";
            value = "<add key='KeyName' value='Value' />";
            ModifyWebConfig(webApp, name, xpath, value, SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode);
            #endregion

            try
            {
                webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RemoveWebEntries(properties);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            RemoveWebEntries(properties);

            try
            {
                SPWebApplication webApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;
                webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
                eventLog.Source = MyOwner;
                eventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private void RemoveWebEntries(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        { 
            SPWebApplication webApp = (SPWebApplication)properties.Feature.Parent;

            List<SPWebConfigModification> modificationsToRemove = new List<SPWebConfigModification>();

            foreach (SPWebConfigModification modification in webApp.WebConfigModifications)
                if (modification.Owner == MyOwner)
                    modificationsToRemove.Add(modification);

            foreach (SPWebConfigModification modification in modificationsToRemove)
                webApp.WebConfigModifications.Remove(modification);

            webApp.Update();
        }

        private void ModifyWebConfig(SPWebApplication webApp, String nameModif, String pathModif, String valueModif, SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType typeModif)
        {
            SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification(nameModif, pathModif);
            modification.Value = valueModif;
            modification.Sequence = 0;
            modification.Type = typeModif;
            modification.Owner = MyOwner;

            try
            {
                webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);
                webApp.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }


    }
```

**However**, to store the custom configurations, I would strongly recommend you to use Web application, Farm or Web level property bags instead.

Comment: This is a good start, but I use `applicationSettings` instead of `appSettings`. So correct me if I'm wrong - my `Path` would be:  
  
`configuration/applicationSettings/MyAssembly.Properties.Settings`, and my `Value` would be:

`<setting name="xxx" serializeAs="String">  
    <value>...</value>  
</setting>`

Comment: The basic `<appSettings>`is easier to deal with - just slap in a `<add key="...." value="..." />` entry and you're done.

Comment: You just access it as `ConfigurationManager["(key)"]` and then it's up to you to know what you're dealing with.

Comment: Falak, I've experienced issues related to removing changes through SPWebConfigModification like some explained here http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2008/01/05/spwebconfigmodifications-top-6-issues/ Have you ever seen issues like Reza describes? And how do you deal with them? Thanks,Tom

Comment: @TomResing entry can be removed if you had set the `Owner` property to some value while adding it.

Comment: Given the weirdness I've seen in the edited question where `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` is unpredictable and web.config is being read from unexpected places, will `appSettings` be any better?

Comment: I believe that the `<appsettings/>` collection in your web.config allows you to store settings in key-value pairs, and can easily be accessed through the System.Configuration

Comment: @FalakMahmood Did you read the article? He does set the owner property.

Comment: @tomResing I have seen the blog but I only had some problems with it because I performed some manual entries in the past. Actually, Name and owner property are represented as a XPath expressions that uniquely identify the config entry. Also, it would interesting to see which account you're using to perform the feature activation? Could you please try the updated code in my post and let me know how to worked for ya?

Comment: @TomResing Please see my updated post!

Comment: @FalakMahmood thanks for the update. Just so you know, I'm not trying to actively troubleshoot an issue. Like your recommendation, I prefer maintaining configuration in other places. Issues I've encountered with SPWebConfigModification in the past (too long to remember the details) are part of that reasoning.

Comment: Please refrain from excessive commenting on posts. Instead use our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) for discussions please!